# How to check if a MIDI device is also a USB device?

Tags: windows, usb, midi, winmm

How can you check if an MIDI device is also an USB device?

Seems that checking for this string "\\?\\usb" in the device identifier is not enough all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CM_Get_Parent` (recursively) to find out whether the MIDI device is connected beneath a USB root port.

Comment: after including the cfgmgr32.h header I get this error: "error C2275 : 'wchar_t' illegal use of this type as an expression", I haven't managed to get rid of it.

Comment: @Dragarro: You're including `windows.h` before `cfgmgr32.h`, right?  Is that error occurring in your code?  In the header file?  Does it occur in a .cpp file that's empty except for `#include <windows.h> #include <cfgmgr32.h>`?

Comment: It doesn't happen in an empty file. I fixed it by removing some variables that were of type wchar_t(they were part of the old implementation), cfgmgr32.h was included after windows.h. Anyway your solution seems to work, thanks